# background image is not showing in div

Tags: html, css

I have a question about the div element. the background image is not showing. can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?  why the background image is not showing?

```css
.banner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)), url(/wall2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner"> </div>
```

Comment: 1) You'll need to quote the string in `url`. 2)  `100%` height might not work if the parent does not have a height. 3) `100vh` for `width` is strange, did you ment `vw` (view-width) instead of view-height?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:  `height: 100vh; width: 100%;`

```css
.banner {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)), url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1665507254439-fe45f1417c13?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxMnx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner"> </div>
```